# InfoPath and UDC communication error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010, infopath-2007

In my SharePoint site, I'm using InfoPath Form Libraries, the InfoPath files uses UDC files to get the data on form load. InfoPath files and UDC are in the same site collection and in same server "Server A".

Now when I try to access the InfoPath files from "Server A", the InfoPath files works perfectly. But when an user access the site and when he tries to add or open a InfoPath file in the SharePoint site from his machine, he gets the following errors, this happnes to the site collection administrator as well.

1.The UDC file cannot be opened. The operation timed out.

2.InfoPath either cannot connect to the data source or the service has timed out.

3.The data connection file could not be accessed.

4.The form cannot run the specified query.

Note:

A. User has access to the SharePoint site, Data Connection Library and releated SharePoint lists.

B. In Central Administration –> General Application Settings –> InfoPath Forms Services –> Configure InfoPath Forms Services: I have enabled "Cross Domain Access for User Form Templates".

C. In Central Administration –> General Application Settings –> InfoPath Forms Services –> Configure InfoPath Forms Services: I have Increased the "Data Connection Timeouts".

D. All the UDC files are approved and Checked in.

E. InfoPath fomrs are not web browsable forms, they are filler forms developed using InfoPath 2007.

I'm using SharePoint 2010, InfoPath 2007 and InfoPath 2010.

**EDIT:**

From "Server B", I created an InfoPath with a data connection accessing the UDC in "Server A", when I previewed it, I'm getting the above mentioned errors.

I'm not able to access the UDC files anywhere in my network, other than "Server A"(all UDC resides in "Server A")

What am I missing.?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are authenticating, I suspect that you are hitting an authentication double-hop issue. The solution is to implement Kerberos... doing so is a bit of a pain, but it means that the users' credentials can be used to access non-SP resources (SQL servers, etc).

The reference document from MS is ~100 pages. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23176

We made some health analyzers to point out Kerberos config issues, since MS didn't. http://sdssharepointlibrary.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Health%20Analyzers%20for%20Delegation&referringTitle=Documentation

Feel free to contact directly if you have other questions/needs.